# Where is the pygame template in Quickly?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

Same as the title says. When I want to create a new **Quickly** project, I don't get the **pygame** template option any longer.

- **ubuntu-application**
- **ubuntu-cli**
- **ubuntu-flash-game**

Those 3 are the templates that are available to use for me right now.

Did they remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the pygame template was removed in Ubuntu 12.04, in [this commit](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~quickly-committers/quickly/trunk/revision/662).

IIRC the rationale was that the pygame template was using *desktopcouch* as a dependency, which is deprecated. My understanding is that it was easier to remove the template rather than reworking it to get rid of *desktopcouch*, as someone mentioned that pygame would be better implemented embedding it.

Comment: @swenix Check the checkmark on the left on the answer if this answers your question, thanks!